# Slime fuzzy completion not working correctly in TTY mode

Tags: terminal-emacs, x11, slime, common-lisp

I have Slime configured with fuzzy completion and it works perfectly when I'm using it in X11 mode (<kbd>M-TAB</kbd>, list of completions pops up in a separate buffer, <kbd>C-n/p</kbd> allows to choose the right completion, <kbd>TAB</kbd> makes use of chosen completion). However, when I run Emacs in TTY mode (`-nw` option), that last step fails, i.e. I get a list of completions, can navigate across them, but pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> on my choice does not select it. I am, however, able to select it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but this also results in a newline being inserted, which is annoying. Any idea why there is such a discrepancy between those two modes?

EDIT:

I'm using Emacs version `26.0.50.2` (but this also happened in previous versions - 24 and 25). My Slime version is `20161109.640` (installed from MELPA). Below is the part of the config relevant to Slime:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Common Lisp ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append auto-mode-alist
          '(("\\.cl\\'" . lisp-mode)
        ("\\.lsp\\'" . lisp-mode))))
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy
           slime-media
           slime-asdf
           slime-tramp))
(setq slime-enable-evaluate-in-emacs t)
(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-autodoc)
(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-trace-dialog)
(setq slime-complete-symbol*-fancy t)
(setq slime-complete-symbol-function 'slime-fuzzy-complete-symbol)
```

Comment: Just a guess: could it be that Slime binds the command you want to the `[tab]` key sequence, instead of binding it to `"\t"`?

Comment: Please post a small init file that reproduces the problem, and tell us what version of Emacs and Slime you're using. Otherwise it's a shot in the dark.